# Trouble with inverse Z-transform and calculating of samples

Tags: homework, z-transform

I have a little problem. I have to solve this task but I can't.

> Z-transform of sequence $\{x(k)\}$ describe by the formula:
>
> $$X(z) = \frac{2.5 -3.15z^{-1} + 1.2 z^{-2}}{1-2.3z^{-1} + 1.2z^{-2}}$$
>
> Calculate of samples $x(-2), x(-1), x(0), x(1)$ and $x(2)$
> double-sides sequence, which correspond this Z-transform.

Thank you very much.

---

"Double-side" sequence I mean sequence like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And I'm trying to solve this task with MatLab, I've used function "iztrans()" (inverse z-transformation) and I've gotten this results (below MatLab code and results):

[image]
[image]

But sequence which I've gotten isn't correct. Could you say what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The poles in the equation are Z=1.5,0.8;hence to be two sided the roc is $0.8<=z<=1.5$
so the 0.8 term is right sided and 1.5 term is left sided let us do partial fractions now $ X(Z)=1+\frac{1.5-0.85z^{-1}} {(1-0.8z^{-1})(1-1.5z^{-1})} $
after doing some maths i got $x(n)=\delta(n)-0.5(0.8)^nu(n)-2(1.5)^nu(-n-1)$
so x(-2)=-0.88888,x(-1)=-1.3333,x(0)=0.5,x(1)=-0.4,x(2)=-0.32.

Comment: Yes, I've got the same results besides x(0), I've got x(0) = 2.5 (why did you get x(0) = 0.5), I decribed my solve [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/inverse-z-transform-where-is-mistake), but answer isn't correct and I don't know why))

Comment: I think partial fraction method is applicable if numerator degree is less than denominator degree so you have done it opposite hence our answers differ at x(0). I hope my point got trough.

Comment: Shouldn't the last term in your expression for $x[n]$ be multiplied with $u[-n-1]$ (instead of $u[-n+1]$)?

Comment: @MattL. Yes I got confused.

Comment: Ch.Siva Ram Kishore, you're right! I wrote description there [(link here)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54466/inverse-z-transform-where-is-mistake/55395#55395).
Thank you everyone!

Comment: @AlexanderLyapunov if you are satisfied with any one's answer accept their answer.